# Elasticsearch spatial index - Точки в полигоне

Tags: php, elasticsearch, spatial

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача - найти все точки, находящиеся в полигоне.
ПРобовал решать стандартным функционалом PHP & MySQL - криво и долго... к сожалению (обработать n тысяч точек = много секунд).

Покопавшись и интернете, нашел описание в ElasticSearch того, что можно индексировать и выдрать нужное с помощью spatial функций.

1 что я сделал - создал индексы:

Примерно так выглядят 4 класса для составления:

```
abstract class ElasticIndex {
protected static
    $_indexName,
    $_indexType;

public static function getIndexType() {
    return static::$_indexType;
}

public static function getIndexName() {
    return static::$_indexType;
}

/**
 * @return array Получаем массив с конфой  индекса
 */
public function getIndexParams() {
    $ip = array();
    $ip['index'] = static::getIndexName();
    $ip['type']  = static::getIndexType();
    $ip['body'] = array(
        'mappings'  =>  $this->_indexes
    );

    return $ip;
}

public static function createPushArray(array $data, $id = 0) {
    $b = array();
    $b['body'] = $data;
    if($id)
        $b['id'] = $id;
    $b['index'] = self::getIndexName();
    $b['type']  = self::getIndexType();
    return $b;
}

protected static function _createQuery($json, $id = 0) {
    $b['index'] = self::getIndexName();
    $b['type']  = self::getIndexType();
    if($id) { $b['id'] = $id; }
    $b['body']  = $json;
    $q = ElasticSearch::getInstance()->search($b);
    $s = ElasticSearch::getRows($q);
    return $s;
}
```

}

Дальше, описал несколько классов с конфигруацией индексов:

```
/**
 * Class sdfCargosElastic Индекс точек
 */
class sdfCargosElastic extends ElasticIndex {
    protected static
        $_indexName = 'sdfCargo',
        $_indexType = 'nominatim';

    protected $_indexes = array(
        '_source'   =>  array('enabled' => true),
        'properties'    =>  array(
            'points'    =>  array('type'    =>  'point')
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Class sdfRoutesElastic Индекс многоугольника
 */
class sdfRoutesElastic extends ElasticIndex {
    protected static
        $_indexName = 'sdfRoute',
        $_indexType = 'nominatim';

    protected $_indexes = array(
        '_source'   =>  array('enabled' => true),

        'properties'    =>  array(
            'crdr'    =>  array('type'    =>  'polygon')
        )
    );
    public static function createQuery($pnt) {

    }
}
```

Вопрос:

Каким образом составить запрос фильтра, чтобы можно было указать ID многоугольника и получить ID's точек в нем ?

Comment: Какой версией _ElasticSearch_ вы пользуетесь? То что я нашел по вашему вопросу это поддержка типов [Geo-point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) и [Geo-Shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) пример поиска по [полигону](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html)